# How to capitalize a string using control lens?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm playing with the `lens` package and I'm trying to capitalize a string using only lens.
Basically I want to call `toUpper` on each first element of every words. That seems to be easy to with it, but I can't figure out at all how to do it. Do I need a traversable ? How do I split by spaces etc ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really an isomorphism to call `words` then `unwords` because it'll convert repeated spaces to single ones, but let's pretend:

```
words :: Iso' String [String]
words = iso Prelude.words Prelude.unwords
```

Now we can capitalize words by building a lens which focuses on the first letter of each word and applying `over` and `toUpper`

```
capitalize :: String -> String
capitalize = over (words . traverse . _head) toUpper
```

Comment: Brilliant! That's what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm trying `let w = iso words unwords  :: Iso' String [String]` in ghci and I get the following error : `No instance for (Profunctor p0) ...`. Any ideas ?

Comment: Mm. Now I have to actually install `lens`. I'll respond in about 20 minutes.

Comment: @mb14 Put the type signature on its own line. If you run `:set +m` first you'll get multiline input in GHCi.  This problem is due to how GHC's type inference works with type signatures standalone vs. inline

Comment: @mb14 Alternatively, run `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction` to get GHCi to interpret it how you'd expect.

Comment: And 25 minutes later... yup! This won't replicate on GHC 7.8. It's a monormorphism restriction thing.

Comment: I wish I could use GHC 7.8. Everytime I tried to install it I got some library conflict (even when I start with a new sandbox)

Comment: @J.Abrahamson I was initially confused on 7.6 because it worked for me, then I remembered that I have my `.ghci` file set to turn off the monomorphism restriction by default.  I turned it back on and got the same error as mb14, it's definitely the cause.

Comment: As annoying as it is to always have to `:set`, I never turn things on in my `.ghci` for that reason—downstream confusion that's hard to debug.

Answer (score 3):

```
capitalize xs = xs & words <&> _head %~ toUpper & unwords
```

Okay, that's the solution, but how to get there? Lets remove some lens parts. Exchange `(<&>)` with `fmap` and `(&)` with `($)`:

```
capitalize xs = unwords $ fmap (_head %~ toUpper) $ words $ xs
```

This looks familar. `_head %~ f` will apply `f` on the first element of the list. At the end, this is (almost<sup>*</sup>) equivalent to

```
capitalize xs = unwords $ fmap (\(x:xs) -> toUpper x : xs) $ words $ xs
```

which you are probably familiar with.

---

<sup>* `_head` also takes care of the empty list case</sup>

Comment: If you're willing to consider `(words, unwords)` an isomorphism then you can do this all with a single call to `over`.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson: Thanks for your additional answer. That's actually the first time I've worked with lens. The tip with `Iso` is great. However, I should take some steps back and read more about Traverseable, I completely forgot about `traverse` and spend too much time looking for an operator (I ended up with `over _words $ fmap (_head %~ toUpper)`).

Comment: I'm happy to consider words and unwords an isomorphism as it just an example about to *traverse* through an isomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

A solution that doesn't collapse repeated spaces:

```
import Control.Lens
import Data.List.Split
import Data.List.Split.Lens
import Data.Char

capitalize :: String -> String
capitalize = view $ splitting (whenElt isSpace) traversed.to (over _head toUpper)
```